# python/GUI creation: how to reconfigure the text of a label to 'match the text of the button clicked'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have looked through multiple related articles on here to do with labels/buttons/configuration and have so far not identified any explaining this exact issue. I have written basic label configuration programs with success previously (using 'functions' and the use of 'command=' as well as 'lambda' etc) but they only involved configuration code in the function using a set string (text="String").
What I am intending to do in this program is change the label text to that of the same text in a 'button', so when the user clicks the button, the label displays the text with an accompanying string ("Contact info for: " + button clicked)

I am sure the issue is with my 'function code' itself (the formatting of the latter part of the line in particular), either that or the 'button creation' line in the 'for loop' below may need editing (or maybe both).

I'm guessing there would be more than 'one route' to approach this, considering all the 'button texts' are also contained within a dictionary as key(name), so any suggestions of any kind, either way would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to Python so I'm sure this will actually be a simple easy problem for experienced coders

```
# The purpose of this program is to produce a GUI that acts as a 'contacts
#info retriever', when a 'contact' 'button' is clicked it displays the contact
#information of that person




# Make a 'dictionary' containing contact info

contacts = { 1: {"Name" : "Max", "Address" : "18 Fake Street, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07542564872"},
           2: {"Name" : "Brian", "Address" : "17 Fake Boulevard, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07895465231"},
           3: {"Name" : "Sally", "Address" : "19 Hill Valley, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07956423145"},
           4: {"Name" : "Steve", "Address" : "22 Fake House, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07456213895"},
           5: {"Name" : "Sara", "Address" : "46 Fake Drive, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07652348192"},
           6: {"Name" : "Kevin", "Address" : "18 Labyrinth Avenue, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07563245196"},
           7: {"Name" : "Paula", "Address" : "38 Fake Drive, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07354695488"},
           8: {"Name" : "Dave", "Address" : "Haystack Farm, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07854623198"},
           9: {"Name" : "Mary", "Address" : "Fake Valley, CA", "Mobile" : "07564289315"},
           10:{"Name" : "Anastasia", "Address" : "Some Street, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07546321595"}}

# Import 'GUI creation' module

import tkinter

# Create a 'window'

window = tkinter.Tk()

# Give the window a 'title'

window.title("Phonebook")

# Import an 'ico' file for icon

window.wm_iconbitmap("Moon Full.ico")


# Create a 'label' that displays opening instruction message at top

lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Click a contact to show their details:")

# 'Pack' the 'label'

lbl.pack()



# A 'function' for the 'reconfiguration' of 'labels' (changing their output)

def changeLabel():
    lbl2.configure(text="Details for " + str(btn))



# 'Dynamically create' 'buttons' using a 'for loop' as so

for i in contacts:

    #creates 'button' for what ever 'sub dictionary' (contact) the 'loop'
    #is currently on

    btn = tkinter.Button(window, text=contacts [i] ["Name"], command=changeLabel)

    #'pack' the 'button'

    btn.pack()



# Create a 'label' to display 'who the info belongs to'
lbl2 = tkinter.Label(window, text="No contact selected")

# Pack label
lbl2.pack()

# Draw the 'window', engage program
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way it to bind the information to the button upon creation, and pass this information as a parameter when the button is clicked:

```
contacts = { 1: {"Name" : "Max", "Address" : "18 Fake Street, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07542564872"},
           2: {"Name" : "Brian", "Address" : "17 Fake Boulevard, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07895465231"},
           3: {"Name" : "Sally", "Address" : "19 Hill Valley, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07956423145"},
           4: {"Name" : "Steve", "Address" : "22 Fake House, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07456213895"},
           5: {"Name" : "Sara", "Address" : "46 Fake Drive, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07652348192"},
           6: {"Name" : "Kevin", "Address" : "18 Labyrinth Avenue, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07563245196"},
           7: {"Name" : "Paula", "Address" : "38 Fake Drive, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07354695488"},
           8: {"Name" : "Dave", "Address" : "Haystack Farm, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07854623198"},
           9: {"Name" : "Mary", "Address" : "Fake Valley, CA", "Mobile" : "07564289315"},
           10:{"Name" : "Anastasia", "Address" : "Some Street, Hollywood", "Mobile" : "07546321595"}}


import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Phonebook")

lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Click a contact to show their details:")
lbl.pack()

def changeLabel(text):
    """A 'function' for the 'reconfiguration' of 'labels' 
    (changing their output)
    """
    lbl2.configure(text="Details for " + text)

for i in contacts:    
    btn = tkinter.Button(window, text=contacts[i]["Name"], command=lambda text=contacts[i]["Name"]:changeLabel(text))
    btn.pack()

lbl2 = tkinter.Label(window, text="No contact selected")
lbl2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

#### Alternatively:

At @BrianOakley's suggestion in the comments: since contacts is global, the code might be a bit easier to debug and maintain if it passed the index to the function rather than have a complex lambda statement. (see code below for this alternate, and arguably more robust solution)

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Phonebook")

lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Click a contact to show their details:")
lbl.pack()

def changeLabel(ndx):
    """A 'function' for the 'reconfiguration' of 'labels' 
    (changing their output)
    """
    lbl2.configure(text="Details for " + contacts[ndx]["Name"])

for i in contacts:    
    btn = tkinter.Button(window, text=contacts[i]["Name"], command=lambda ndx=i: changeLabel(ndx))
    btn.pack()

lbl2 = tkinter.Label(window, text="No contact selected")
lbl2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thankyou Reblochon, that certainly looks promising, I will test it out and let you know

Comment: Spot on, it worked, thanks alot I did suspect 'lambda' could somehow  be used in this, but previously I had only used it for changing the text of the button itself etc

Comment: since `contacts` is global, the code would be a bit easier to debug and maintain if you just passed the index to the function rather than have a complex `lambda` statement.

Comment: Agreed, this is a great suggestion, thank you @BrianOakley. I posted an addition to the answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley funnily enough, just before logging into this today, I just finished the program and tried that exact method for adding additional labels  (Mobile/Address) though I had issues with getting the function to be able to access  the dictionary (it produced an error), this made me presume dictionaries weren't accessible from within a function but perhaps this was my own misformatting as my 'button creation code' was different to yours, I used 'num = contact [i] ["Mobile"]' in a similar method as 'passing' in the text 'argument'. In the end I opted for passing in text for data